# How it's possible to determine the output frequency of STM32 without oscilloscope?

Tags: stm32, frequency-measurement

I am implementing a frequency meter on my STM32F4, but to do that I need to know exact frequency of the timer fed on GPIO pin.

Is it somehow possible to determine that without using external frequency meter or oscilloscope?

Comment: Do you know the approximate frequency?

Comment: @jippie I do know approximate frequency. I created a small program on arduino which catches rising edge and calls interrupt which shows delta time since previous rising edge. I am just afraid that it is not precise enough (and won't go faster than 1KHz)

Comment: You could use a counter (or a cascade of counters) to pre-divide the input frequency before measuring it. You could also consider using your computer sound card input to measure the signal (where you can sample at frequencies of at least 44.1kHz, most likely more).